# Exception while creating koloboke map. (Internal Runtime Error) java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, hashmap, koloboke

I am hitting the following exception while I try to create a koloboke map.
My map is something like this,

```
private final HashObjObjMap<String, Map<String, String>> qosMap;
qosMap = HashObjObjMaps.<String, Map<String, String>>newMutableMap();
```

### Exception at runtime.

```
(Internal Runtime Error) java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:365) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.access$700(ServiceLoader.java:323) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator$2.run(ServiceLoader.java:407) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:409) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
        at net.openhft.koloboke.collect.map.hash.HashObjObjMaps.getDefaultFactory(HashObjObjMaps.java:58) ~[koloboke-api-jdk6-7.jar:?]
        at net.openhft.koloboke.collect.map.hash.HashObjObjMaps.newMutableMap(HashObjObjMaps.java:83) ~[koloboke-api-jdk6-7.jar:?]
```

I see a similar issue reported here, https://github.com/leventov/Koloboke/issues/34.
Fix is to have both api and impl jars in the classpath. 
I verified my classpath by using `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` which shows both jars in the classpath.

Can anyone help me with this issue?